# How do I constrain texts and elements inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage using only CSS & HTML

[image: This is what the homepage looks like]

Everything looks fine until I zoom in. Once I zoom in the letters start to flow out of the div.

[image]

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem has to do with responsive webdesign. By default people create there website for there own screens. But not everyone has the same screen resolution or viewport etc as you have.

The solution:

**Media queries:**

With media queries you can alter you css code when the user has a different resolution/viewport or is resizing there screen.

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .h2 {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

This will change the font of a the h2 tag to 10px when the screen width of the user is smaller then 979px. I will provide you with a link to a w3Schools page so you can see what kind of attributes the @media rule has.

[Media queries w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

tip:
You can see your resolution by opening the chrome developer tools and resizing your browser.(left top corner)

If you have any future questions please let me know I will explain some more about media queries.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply.

But I still don't get it.
Here's the link to [my site](http://adityathebe.com/ku).
can you see what's wrong?

Comment: It's this height of your .content div. You should alter the height of your div to be alway 100% or you should write a media query to alter the size of the fonts when the screens is smaller then a certain amount of pixels.

Comment: I set the content div height to 100% and it didn't work.